# Exporting R data.frame/tbl to Google BigQuery table

Tags: python, r, dataframe, google-bigquery

I know it's possible to import Google BigQuery tables to R through `bigrquery` library. But is it possible to export tables/data frames created in R to Google BigQuery as new tables?

Basically, is there an R equivalent of Python's `temptable.insert_data(df)` or `df.to_sql()` ?

thanks for your help,
Kasia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `bigrquery` package does the job with `insert_upload_job()`. In the package documentation, it says this function

*> is only suitable for relatively small datasets*

but it doesn't specify any size limits. For me, it's been working for tens of thousands of rows.